# How to Improve Performance of Kafka Producer when used in Synchronous Mode

Tags: asynchronous, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have developed a `Kafka version : 0.9.0.1` application that cannot afford to lose any messages.

I have a constraint that the messages must be consumed in the correct sequence.

To ensure I do not loose any messages I have implemented Retries within my application code and configured my Producer to `ack=all`.

To enforce exception handling and to Fail Fast I immediately `get()` on the returned `Future` from `Producer.send()`, e.g.

```
final Future<RecordMetadata> futureRecordMetadata = KAFKA_PRODUCER.send(producerRecord);
futureRecordMetadata.get();
```

This approach works fine for guaranteeing the delivery of all messages, however the performance is completely unacceptable.

For example it takes 34 minutes to send 152,125 messages with `ack=all`.

When I comment out the futureRecordMetadata.get(), I can send 1,089,125 messages in 7 minutes.

When I change `ack=all` to `ack=1` I can send 815,038 in 30 minutes. Why is there such a big difference between `ack=all` and `ack=1`?

However by not blocking on the `get()` I have no way of knowing if the message arrived safely.

I know I can pass a `Callback` into the send and have Kafka retry for me, however this approach has a drawback that messages may be consumed out of sequence.

I thought `request.required.acks` config could save the day for me, however when I set any value for it I receive this warning

```
130 [NamedConnector-Monitor] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - The configuration request.required.acks = -1 was supplied but isn't a known config.
```

Is it possible to asynchronously send Kafka messages, with a guarantee they will ALWAYS arrive safely and in the correct sequence?

**UPDATE 001**

Is there anyway I can consume messages in kafka message KEY order direct from the TOPIC?

Or would I have to consume messages in offset order then sort programmatically
to Kafka message Key order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expect a total order, the send performance is bad. (actually total order scenario is very rare).
If Partition order are acceptable, you can use multiple thread producer. One producer/thread for each partition.

Comment: We can only use one partition  as this is how we guarantee  send sequence

Comment: what kind of data you are handling? database binlog?

Comment: Database before and after rows following DBMS inserts, update, and deletes. That's why my messages have to be kept in the correct order